# displaying an object by unknown index in object array using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I have an object array where I need to use Knockout.js:

```
array([
    { name: apple, ID: 100 },
    { name: orange, ID: 200},
    { name: banana, ID: 300 }
]);
```

The array is dynamic in that at any time during the day each row can change location or index (but the contents of the row remain the same), for example:

```
array([
    { name: orange, ID: 200},
    { name: apple, ID: 100},
    { name: banana, ID: 300 }
]);
```

I would like to change the display name of 'apple' to 'peach' irrespective of where the row might move to during the day.I have tried the following code but this does not seem to work:

```js
ko.utils.arrayForEach(array.rowItems, function(item,index) {

if(item = array.rowItems.ID = 100))

return array.rowItems[item = (array.rowItems.ID = 100)].name = "peach"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I have tried using indexOf and findIndex as well.

Comment: Is property name a variable or string? Maybe you are missing enclosing quotes?

Comment: I'm failing to see why you keep writing `item = array.rowItems.ID = 100` all over the place. I suggest you remove this unused `item` assignment of your code and use `==` for comparison

Comment: What's rowItems?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just looping items inside an array then you can have the solution below.

```
var array = [
    { name: "apple", ID: 100 },
    { name: "orange", ID: 200},
    { name: "banana", ID: 300 }
]

ko.utils.array.forEach(array, function(item, index) {
    if(item.ID === 100){
        item.name = "peach";
    }
});
```

You do not need to reference the array inside the forEach item callback, since you only are updating the property of each item in the loop.